# Inject gyroscope events with xposed

Tags: android, android-sensors, inject, gyroscope, xposed

i want to simulate gyroscope data when button is pressed.
Is it possible to inject those events programmatically by using xposed module

Comment: Have you tried the [Virtual Sensor module](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-virtualsensor-emulate-gyroscope-t3424555)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved by hook dispatchSensorEvent method

```
                   findAndHookMethod(
                            "android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue",
                            lpparam.classLoader, "dispatchSensorEvent", int.class, float[].class, int.class, long.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
                                @Override
                                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) {                        
                                Object systemSensorManager = XposedHelpers.getObjectField(param.thisObject, "mManager");
                                    SparseArray<Sensor> sensors = getSensors(systemSensorManager);
                                    int handle = (Integer) (param.args[0]); 
                                    Sensor sensor = sensors.get(handle);
                                    XposedBridge.log("sensor Name:"+sensor.getName() +" Value= "+ Arrays.toString((float[]) param.args[1]) );

            }
//getSensors method
    protected SparseArray<Sensor> getSensors(Object systemSensorManager) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<Integer, Sensor> map = (HashMap<Integer, Sensor>) XposedHelpers.getObjectField(systemSensorManager, "mHandleToSensor");

            SparseArray<Sensor> sensors = new SparseArray<>(map.size());
            for (Integer i : map.keySet()) {
                sensors.append(i, map.get(i));
            }
            return sensors;
        }
```